# Dividing correlated query by uncorrelated query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write a SELECT statement that will calculate a percentage based off of the results of two queries.

I need to divide the results of the two subqueries that generate VulnerabilityCount and VulnerabilityCountAll. I am also rounding the result to two decimal places.

Here is the code:

```
 SELECT tblControl.ControlName,
     (SELECT COUNT(CONVERT(REAL,tblVulnerability.VulnerabilityID))
     FROM tblVulnerability
     WHERE tbl.Vulnerability.ControlID = tblControl.ControlID ) AS VulnerabilityCount,

     (SELECT COUNT(CONVERT(REAL,tblVulnerability.VulnerabilityID))
     FROM tblVulnerability) AS VulnerabilityCountAll, 

     /* This is where I am dividing the two subqueries */
     (SELECT(ROUND(CONVERT(REAL,(
          (SELECT COUNT(CONVERT(REAL,tblVulnerability.VulnerabilityID))
      FROM tblVulnerability
      WHERE tbl.Vulnerability.ControlID = tblControl.ControlID )
      /
     (SELECT COUNT(CONVERT(REAL,tblVulnerability.VulnerabilityID))
     FROM tblVulnerability)
     )),2))) AS Percentage

 FROM tblControl
 WHERE tblControl.Effectiveness = '10'
 ORDER BY VulnerabilityCount DESC, tblControl.ControlName ASC
```

The query will run, but it generates a value of '0' for the Percentage column instead of the true percentages.

Comment: I'll bet there's a simpler way to write the query.  How about providing sample data and desired results.  A SQL Fiddle is also a big help.

Answer (score 0):

The output of your count functions are integers.  You are dividing an integer by an integer, and so the output type of the operation is integer.  You should do the conversion to real on the count value instead of the parameters... like this:

```
 SELECT tblControl.ControlName,

     (SELECT CONVERT(REAL,COUNT(tblVulnerability.VulnerabilityID))
     FROM tblVulnerability
     WHERE tbl.Vulnerability.ControlID = tblControl.ControlID ) AS VulnerabilityCount,

     (SELECT CONVERT(REAL,COUNT(tblVulnerability.VulnerabilityID))
     FROM tblVulnerability) AS VulnerabilityCountAll, 

     /* This is where I am dividing the two subqueries */
     (SELECT(ROUND(CONVERT(REAL,(
          (SELECT CONVERT(REAL,COUNT(tblVulnerability.VulnerabilityID))
      FROM tblVulnerability
      WHERE tbl.Vulnerability.ControlID = tblControl.ControlID )
      /
     (SELECT CONVERT(REAL,COUNT(tblVulnerability.VulnerabilityID))
     FROM tblVulnerability)
     )),2))) AS Percentage
 FROM tblControl
 WHERE tblControl.Effectiveness = '10'
 ORDER BY VulnerabilityCount DESC, tblControl.ControlName ASC
```

Although probably a more efficient and clear query would use a join with a group by:

```
 select tblControl.ControlName,
    COUNT(tblVulnerability.VulnerabilityID) VulnerabilityCount,
    (select COUNT(VulnerabilityID) from tblVulnerability) as VulnerabilityCountAll,
    CONVERT(REAL,COUNT(tblVulnerability.VulnerabilityID))
        / (select COUNT(VulnerabilityID) from tblVulnerability) AS Percentage
 from tblControl
 join tblVulnerability
 on tblControl.ControlID = tblVulnerability.ControlID
 where tblControl.Effectiveness = '10'
 Group by tblControl.ControlName 
 ORDER BY VulnerabilityCount DESC, tblControl.ControlName ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I find lot of missing pieces in your question. A sample data and what you are expecting will help to provide accurate answer. I tried to answer with the logic you have in yor query.
If you meant you ran the query you have provided above I believe it would have thrown error out because you have 
**tbl.Vulnerability**.ControlID = tblControl.ControlID 
I believe the table name is tblVulnerability.

And for count why would you need a convert the ID to Real type?? I am not sure if the logic or the need is to Sum, I am providing answer based on count as stated in your question. Hope this helps.

```
 with VC
 (
 select tblVulnerability.ControlID , 
 count(*) over (Partition by ControlID) as ControlVulnerabilityCount
 , count(*) as VulnerabilityCount
 from tblVulnerability
 )
 select tblControl.ControlName,VC.CntV  AS VulnerabilityCount,
 (VC.ControlVulnerabilityCount/ VC.VulnerabilityCount) as Percentage
 from tblControl tc
 join VC on VC.ControlID = tc.ControlID
  WHERE tblControl.Effectiveness = '10'
  order by VC.ControlVulnerabilityCount desc, tblControl.ControlName ASC
```